# Bypassing captcha by changing Headers in the request

Tags: python, web-scraping, web, https

I'm trying to get a large amount of data from a certain website and after a lot of research I noticed that every time I change headers in the request I manage to bypass the Captcha ("ShieldSquare Captcha").
I'm currently trying to understand which of the parameters in the headers are meaningful so that in every request the server will think that I reached it in a different way.

I searched in the forum, on the Internet and with the help of Chat GPT for a source to generate headers in a random way, but most of the sources are old or do not work fully.

I would appreciate help if there is anyone here who has experience.

These are the functions I am currently using but they work partially

```
def generate_http_headers():
    user_agents = generate_user_agent()
    accept_types = ["text/html", "application/json", "application/xml", "text/plain"]
    accept_encodings = ["gzip", "deflate", "br"]
    language_codes = ["en-US", "en-GB", "fr-FR", "es-ES", "de-DE"]
    
    headers = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        "User-Agent": user_agents,
        "Accept": random.choice(accept_types),
        "Accept-Encoding": random.choice(accept_encodings),
        "Accept-Language": random.choice(language_codes),
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    }
    
    return headers


def generate_user_agent():
    # Randomly choose parameters for user agent
    NAVIGATOR = ['chrome', 'firefox'] 
    OS = ['mac', 'linux']
    DEVICE_TYPE = ['desktop', 'smartphone']
    
    navigator = random.choice(NAVIGATOR)
    os = random.choice(OS)
    device_type = random.choice(DEVICE_TYPE)

    # Generate user agent string with chosen parameters
    ua = user_agent.generate_user_agent(os=os, navigator=navigator, device_type=device_type)
    print(ua)
    return ua
```